# Java Switch Statememt - Constant Expression Required Using Public Enum from Abstract Class

Tags: java, android, enums, switch-statement

I have written code working with a protocol I have design on top of websockets for a project creating an Android App.

I have a class which handles the websocket communication using the Autobahn library `weCommunicationManager`.

I have a number of variables and tags which are needed to process the received JSON messages coming over websockets to the app from my server.

To keep things separate and in one place, I have created an abstract class `ExICSProtocol` which holds the tags as public static members so they can be referenced from wherever necessary.

Within the received messages is an integer value for the message type which I need to be able to switch on to define how to process that particular received message.

For this I have implemented a public enum in the ExICSProtocol class as follows,

```
public static enum MESSAGE_TYPE{
    PROTOCOL_HANDSHAKE(0),
    USER_CONNECTED(1),
    USER_DISCONNECTED(2),
    SYSTEM_STATE(3),
    CHANGE_ROOM(4),
    EXAM_START(5),
    EXAM_PAUSE(6),
    EXAM_STOP(7),
    EXAM_XTIME(8),
    SEND_MESSAGE(9),
    SUCCESS(69),
    FAILURE(-1),
    TERMINATE_CONNECTION(-2);

    private int code;

    MESSAGE_TYPE(int code){
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getCode(){
        return this.code;
    }
}
```

I am trying to use this in the wsCommunicationManager code as follows,

```
private static void handleMessage(String message){
    try{
        JSONObject messageObject = new JSONObject(message);
        JSONObject messageHeader = messageObject.getJSONObject(ExICSProtocol.TAG_HEADER);
        JSONObject messagePayload = messageObject.getJSONObject(ExICSProtocol.TAG_PAYLOAD);

        int messageType = messageHeader.getInt(ExICSProtocol.TAG_MESSAGE_TYPE);


        switch(messageType){
            case ExICSProtocol.MESSAGE_TYPE.PROTOCOL_HANDSHAKE.getCode():
                //DO SOMETHING HERE
                break;

            ...

            default:
                throw new ExICSException("Unknown Message Type Received");
                break;
        }
    }catch (JSONException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse received message " + message, e);
    }catch (ExICSException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "Excaption Handling Message Occurred", e);
    }
}
```

I am getting errors flagged up under `ExICSProtocol.MESSAGE_TYPE.PROTOCOL_HANDSHAKE.getCode():` saying that a constant expression is required.  This however SHOULD be constant?

I have tried a few different things, moving the enum to the class where it is being used; same problem.  Making the private int held by the enum public so it can directly be accessed; same problem.

I have seen lots of examples of enums being used in switch statements, but non quite like I am.  Am I missing something in my declaration or initialization, or am trying to do something that won't work.

I know there are relatively simple workarounds such as just defining the numerical type codes as public static final ints, but I wanted the type codes to be held together under MESSAGE_TYPE if possible.

Comment: It isn't a constant, it is a method call...

Comment: I also tried making the int "code" itself public and access that directly, removing the method call, but this gives the same error, as I said in the question, e.g `ExICSProtocol.MESSAGE_TYPE.PROTOCOL_HANDSHAKE.code`

Comment: Well, it still isn't a constant; it is a field access. Only enum values are (in fact, they are classes, loaded at runtime as the same time as their enclosing class).

Comment: Bear in mind that usage of Enums are discouraged on Android platform.

Answer (score 5):

You could add a getFromCode(int code) static method into your MESSAGE_TYPE enum like this:

```
public static MESSAGE_TYPE getFromCode(int code) {
    for(MESSAGE_TYPE mt : MESSAGE_TYPE.values())
        if(mt.code == code)
            return mt;

    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

And then in your handleMessage:

```
MESSAGE_TYPE messageType = MESSAGE_TYPE.getByCode(messageHeader.getInt(ExICSProtocol.TAG_MESSAGE_TYPE));


switch(messageType){
    case PROTOCOL_HANDSHAKE:
        //handle handshake...
```

Comment: Just added this to the code and worked like a charm, great work, looks nicer too (y)

Answer (score 5):

As you've seen, calling a method doesn't count as a [constant expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

The cleaner solution (IMO) is to have a static method within your enum:

```
// Enum renamed to comply with conventions
public enum MessageType {

    private static final Map<Integer, MessageType> codeMap = new HashMap<>();
    // Can't do this in the constructor, as the codeMap variable won't have been
    // initialized
    static {
        for (MessageType type : MessageType.values()) {
            codeMap.put(type.getCode(), type);
        }
    }

    public static MessageType fromCode(int code) {
        return codeMap.get(code);
    }
}
```

Then in your wsCommunicationManager code:

```
int messageCode = messageHeader.getInt(ExICSProtocol.TAG_MESSAGE_TYPE);
MessageType messageType = MessageType.fromCode(messageCode);
if (messageType == null) {
    // Unknown message code. Do whatever...
}

switch(messageType) {
    case MessageType.PROTOCOL_HANDSHAKE:
        ...
}
```

Basically, go from the "integer-oriented" to the "object-oriented" world as early as you can. This is a bit like parsing numeric and date-based user input early instead of passing strings around - it's just that in your case the surrogate representation is an `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer

Comment: Are there any benefits to this or Icewind's way, versus that of 323go as far as you're concerned?

Comment: @o0rebelious0o: This doesn't need to create a new array of all values (via the `values()` method) and search through them linearly on each call. It does box the `int`, admittedly - but for low values that won't actually allocate a new object. This is definitely cleaner (IMO) than 323go's approach of just having a bunch of constant integers. It's more object-oriented - you may well find you're able to add more functionality into `MessageType` over time.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your enum does something else that you didn't show us above, this is not a very good use of enums. For this particular case, a static class might be more useful (and readable):

```
public class MessageType {
    public static final int PROTOCOL_HANDSHAKE = 0;
    public static final int USER_CONNECTED = 1;
    ....
}
```

Then in your switch statement, you can use

```
switch( messageType ) {
    case MessageType.PROTOCOL_HANDSHAKE:
        ....
        break;
```

This is essentially the contract class pattern that Android advocates in other areas (such as ContentResolver, Database, etc).

Comment: I actually tried the static class already but I added it as an inner class to the ExICS protocol and so wasn't working.  Maybe implementing it as a class in its own right would have been better

Comment: You can make it a public or static class, and then access it elsewhere, if needed, also. I'm assuming that in this case, performance is an issue, which would make this solution preferable over the enum and HashMap acrobatics.

Comment: I think you could be right, Having the constants baked into the bytecode would definitely be preferred to having to make calls to fetch values from data structures, risking npe's etc

Answer (score 1):

You are using a function which is evaluated on runtime. Putting the same value in an int would also not work, because it is also evaluated at runtime. 
Putting the value in an `private final static int` would work because that is evaluated on compile time and is therefore a constant expression.

Try something like

```
private final static int PROTOCOL_HANDSHAKE = 0;
```

and do this in your switch statement

```
case PROTOCOL_HANDSHAKE:
//Do something
```

Comment: I know that would work, I've been deliberately trying to avoid that though so I could keep the various message types under the MESSAGE_TYPES umbrella, hence trying to get the enum working.  That's my fallback plan though